# Java sqlite ch-werner Wrapper?

Tags: java, database, sqlite, jdbc

Would someone be able to give my some example code on how i would use http://www.ch-werner.de/javasqlite wrapper??

Im using eclipse and i added the SQLite jar file to my project and linked it to the build path.
I have also added the database to my workspace..

Ive imported th SQLite.* in my class.

So what do i have to do now..
create connection
Open connection
do whatever i have to do
close connection

I get these main points but i dont know how to write the code for it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wrapper is a JDBC driver; you access it like any other JDBC driver.
Just read [any random JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html).

The JDBC URLs needed to connect to SQLite database files are described on the page you've linked to.